# How to delete bones hierarchy?

Tags: armature, bones

Good evening. I have additional bones hierarchy in my file, which I want to delete:

[image]

I can't just delete it in viewport, because it's overlapping with main skeleton and it's too hard to select it:

[image]

How can I just select all bones hierarchy and delete it? I don't have that options in outliner:
[image]

Comment: You can't select a bone from Outlines? ... But in Viewport you can?

Comment: @vklidu I can select just one bone in outliner but I can't select hierarchy of bones and can't delete it. I've added screenshot.

Comment: @james_t I don't need to hide it. I need to delete it and assign weight to updated bones hierarchy. If I'll export it in ue5 I will still have this bones.

Comment: What about selecting the parent and then *Select >> Similar >> Children* ?   Or perhaps in your case if all parent and child bones begin with "WK" then perhaps select >> Pattern ?

Comment: @james_t Yes! It works perfectly (Select >> Similar >> Children). Can you post it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UI approach...

What about selecting the parent and then Select >> Similar >> Children ? Or perhaps in your case if all parent and child bones begin with "WK" then perhaps select >> Pattern ?

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this script.   It assumes you've put your armature in EDIT mode and have selected a parent bone.  It will remove all recursive child bones in the hierarchy and then also remove the selected (parent) bone.

```
import bpy

o = bpy.context.object
b = o.data.edit_bones.active
for c in b.children_recursive:
    bpy.context.object.data.edit_bones.remove( c )
bpy.context.object.data.edit_bones.remove( b )
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting error:

bpy.context.object.data.edit_bones.remove( b )
    ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Maybe, I'm doing something wrong? I just pasted it in console.

Comment: When I'm trying to use text file I'm getting another error:
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "rig" not found'

Comment: @Сергей, those lines were too specific for my test rig (had the name 'rig').  I cleaned out two lines that weren't necessary.